# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mini_project`.`tbl_login`, CONSTRAINT `FK_tbl_login_tbl_userinfo` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `tbl_userinfo` (`userId`))

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a row in a table which has a foreing key that references userID in tbl_userinfo.

You are trying to input a value that's not inside tbl.userinfo, and since there is an referencial integrity constraint, you can't do that.

More info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

> Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing back to its parent. The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child table.
>
> It will reject any INSERT or UPDATE operation that attempts to create a foreign key value in a child table if there is no a matching candidate key value in the parent table.